# Dynamic analysis - CLR profiler?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, dynamic-analysis

I am kinda new to this and would need to confirm, MS CLR Profiler, is it a dynamic analysis tool? Will it be able to find some memory leaks or for this I would need more sophisticated tool?

Comment: CLR Profiler is worth what you paid for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally been very happy with ANTS memory profiler for memory leaks diagnostics. MS CLR Profiler is, as far as I know, considered obsolete, and Microsoft created new tool for this purpose.

PerfView

- [Perfview release announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2011/12/28/publication-of-the-perfview-performance-analysis-tool.aspx)
- [Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567)
- [Tutorials](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial)

Comment: Thank you. And I am I right if I say it is dynamic analysis tool?

Comment: Yes, it analyses state of the application which changes over time, in other words, it analyses dynamic data. I don't know that there is a definition of term 'dynamic analysis tool', so I'm only expressing my view.